# Particular Wi-Fi suddenly disappeared from the network list

Tags: networking, internet

I was playing a game in Steam and when it tried to connect to the Internet, suddenly the wi-fi connection got lost and I am unable to get it back on the network list despite reboots of both the laptop and the router. There are tons of other networks on the list, but none are mine. The network works fine on my tablet PC. A strange thing is that when I plug the wire directly to the laptop, it does show it as connected, but won't load pages. I tried booting another kernel in GRUB, but it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the router set the wifi channel number to 13, and seems like my laptop doesn't support it. Restricting the channel numbers to 1-11 worked!